# Best practice on app architecture when parsing a JSON with a recycler view?

Tags: android, json, parsing, model, architecture

Learning how to write apps in Android. The lesson is covering the use of recycler views and parsing JSON files acquired using an API. The instructor put the code to load the JSON file and its corresponding array list in the adapter class. This intuitively feels wrong, given what I've read about separations of concern. However, on android's developer website, it seems to imply models should not be saved in the Main Activity because we don't own Main Activity (and the android OS can kill this activity).

Where would be the best place to write code to load and parse a JSON file in this case? Perhaps it doesn't matter because all the data is retrieved remotely? Still, is there a general rule of thumb? Where are models generally stored?

Comment: Might be helpful to post the related code.